# change format date datepicker angular material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material, date-format

I am learning and trying to understand how the angularJS framework works, I managed to display a datepicker but I can not change the format of the current date (mm-dd-yyyy). I want to change this format to the local date of the user, fr-FR, en-GB ...

I saw this [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#internationalization) there but I do not know in which part of the code paste the examples ...

I also tried this

```
 angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']);
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.config(function($interpolateProvider){
            $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
        });
        myAppModule.config(function($mdDateLocaleProvider) {

            // Example of a French localization.
            $mdDateLocaleProvider.months = ['janvier', 'février', 'mars'];
            $mdDateLocaleProvider.shortMonths = ['janv', 'févr', 'mars'];
            $mdDateLocaleProvider.days = ['dimanche', 'lundi', 'mardi'];
            $mdDateLocaleProvider.shortDays = ['Di', 'Lu', 'Ma'];

            // Can change week display to start on Monday.
            $mdDateLocaleProvider.firstDayOfWeek = 1;

            // Optional.
            $mdDateLocaleProvider.dates = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

            // Example uses moment.js to parse and format dates.
            $mdDateLocaleProvider.parseDate = function(dateString) {
                var m = moment(dateString, 'L', true);
                return m.isValid() ? m.toDate() : new Date(NaN);
            };

            $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function(date) {
                var m = moment(date);
                return m.isValid() ? m.format('L') : '';
            };

            $mdDateLocaleProvider.monthHeaderFormatter = function(date) {
                return myShortMonths[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getFullYear();
            };

            // In addition to date display, date components also need localized messages
            // for aria-labels for screen-reader users.

            $mdDateLocaleProvider.weekNumberFormatter = function(weekNumber) {
                return 'Semaine ' + weekNumber;
            };

            $mdDateLocaleProvider.msgCalendar = 'Calendrier';
            $mdDateLocaleProvider.msgOpenCalendar = 'Ouvrir le calendrier';

            // You can also set when your calendar begins and ends.
            $mdDateLocaleProvider.firstRenderableDate = new Date(1776, 6, 4);
            $mdDateLocaleProvider.lastRenderableDate = new Date(2012, 11, 21);
        });
```

**in the html code:**

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="creation" ui-date="{ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }"></md-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it with ng-model-options? Like their api talks:

mdDatepicker: 
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDatepicker

ngModelOptions: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#usage

PD: Remember you're using angular material for angular 1 version